# Package and stacks with the same name

Tags: ros, stacks, packages

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Can packages and stacks share the same name?  Will having a stack called foo and a package called foo cause problems?

My use case is that I have a stack called foo which contains package foo and package bar.

The local ROS tools are behaving, but I am not sure if this subtly breaks something.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/10796/package-and-stacks-with-the-same-name/) by [adasta](https://answers.ros.org/users/52/adasta/) on ROS Answers with karma: 508 on 2011-08-02

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is not a recommended practice.  You can have a [unary stack](http://www.ros.org/reps/rep-0109.html) where a package is also a stack.  Most of the tools are robust to it, however there are several edge cases which this will break.  Most obvious is roscd, as well as indexing and documentation will be broken as packages and stacks share a namespace.  Getting REP 109 to work was hard.  The package and stack are obviously at different scopes, they should be able to be named differently.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2011-08-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Patrick Bouffard](https://answers.ros.org/users/12/patrick-bouffard/) on 2011-08-02**:
Aren't unary stacks a bit different from what he's asking about? In his case there would still be a foo stack directory above the foo package directory vs. a single dir. Incidentally I notice that at http://www.ros.org/wiki/roscd it isn't documented that you can roscd .